# Current page reload from directive

Tags: angularjs, controller

I know current page can be reload from the directive too. But, I am newbie, don't know how it can be done.

Below is my directive, from where I want to reload page e.g.

```
http://myproject/die/ap/assess.php#/reading/827/3/2378/2


.directive('popupdirective', function($log, $compile, $controller, $http, $templateCache, $rootScope){
return {
restrict: 'A',
scope:{popView:"@",getdata:"="},
link:function(scope,element,attr,pCtlr){
angular.element(".pop-window-close span.fa.fa-times").click(function(){
angular.element(".pop-window-wrapper").hide();
/* I want redirect from here */
});})
```